# Rectangle size not matching cell range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a rectangular shape. But, the size is not matching what I intend to put.
Also, I cannot set the column width to 3.5. It makes the column width 3.55. Doesnt matter if I change it via VBA macro or right click on a column and try to change it. Is this a glitch on Excel?
3 works fine. 3,5 give 3.55

So, I physically changed the columns widths to 3 for the first 100 columns.
When I run the following code:

```
Sub Rectangle()
Dim shp As Shape

Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, Range("D5").Left, Range("D5").Top, Range("B5:D5").Width, 50)

End Sub
```

it gives me the following output:
[image: Output 1]

If i try to make a longer one, like this:

```
Sub Rectangle()
Dim shp As Shape

Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, Range("D5").Left, Range("D5").Top, Range("D5:P5").Width, 50)

End Sub
```

it gives me the following output:
[image: Output 2]

Everytime I try a longer width, I lose more width from the range.

```
Sub Rectangle()
Dim shp As Shape

Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, Range("D5").Left, Range("D5").Top, Range("D5:Z5").Width, 50)

End Sub
```

Following is the output
[image: Output 3]

Is this also an Excel glitch? Is there a workaround this?

Comment: I [can't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19W0R.png) reproduce this and suspect the issue may be somewhere else.

Comment: Indeed. I can see that. What about the column width?
Wonder why it is not working correctly for me. Lets see if someone else have had this problem.

Comment: Look here for an explanation: the visual width depends e.g. on  font and font size of normal style. Moreover it is calculated --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/determine-column-widths or here https://www.businessbrains.ie/excel-column-sizes-units-measurements/

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will read through it.
However, I did not change the font in the excel. The font is whatever is at default when you open a new excel workbook (Calibri size 11)

Comment: Do what you need in three steps, create the shape, size it, then reposition it. This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

- I can't figure out what's the root cause. But there is a walkaround solution.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Rectangle()
    Dim shp As Shape
    
    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, _
        Range("D5").Left, Range("D5").Top, _
        Range("P5").Offset(0, 1).Left - Range("D5").Left, 50)
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I am still getting the same result using your code :(
The rectangle stops slightly before end of Column P

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue on my pc. It's no way to debug. Is the `slightly difference` with my walkaround solution fixed if you change the right end cell? Let's try chchange `Range("P5")` to Range("AA5"). If the difference is fixed, then you can add an offset value on width arguement.

Comment: No, it’s the same condition. Seems like it’s a glitch on Excel. I ran it on my colleagues Laptop and it is showing fine. On mine it shows a little shorter.

Answer (score 0):

As a shape can't be reliably aligned with the columns of your sheet, I suggest to not use shapes for your timespan indication.

Instead, and specifically as a column in your spreadsheet conforms to a working day, use cell fill color to visually highlight the time span.

---

**Update after your comment:**

(*"I wanted to use shapes so that the schedule is easily modifiable by dragging the shapes around, if required, once the schedule is prepared."*)

If you merge the cells, you can move them around as a block. You can merge a range of cells with:

```
Range("C6:H6").Merge
```

and define a color for the range, e.g. with:

```
Range("C6:H6").Interior.Color = RGB(64, 128, 200)
```

Then, moving the mouse to any border of this range, the cursor changes to a four directional arrow and you can grab the range and move it as you please.

Comment: I wanted to use shapes so that the schedule is easily modifiable by dragging the shapes around, if required, once the schedule is prepared.